# Converting 1-bit image loaded with Magick++ to HBITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, imagemagick, magick++

I'm wondering if it is possible to convert 1-bit image that I loaded with Magick++ (`Magick::Image image; image.read(path);`) to a HBITMAP with depth equal to 1 (similar to what you would get by such call `CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, depth, data);`.

Naive attempts like `CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, depth, image.getConstPixels(0, 0, width, height));` of course didn't work - ImageMagick data is clearly stored in a different way. I am able to copy that data properly using `BITMAP` container (not full code):

```
bitmap.bmWidth = image->image()->columns;
bitmap.bmHeight = image->image()->rows;
bitmap.bmWidthBytes = 4 * bitmap.bmWidth;
bitmap.bmPlanes = 1;
bitmap.bmBitsPixel = 32;
...
for (y = 0; y < (ssize_t)image->image()->rows; y++) {
    p = GetVirtualPixels(image->image(), 0, y, image->image()->columns, 1, exception);
    if (!p) break;

    for (x = 0; x < (ssize_t)image->image()->columns; x++)
    {
        q->rgbRed = ScaleQuantumToChar(GetPixelRed(image->image(), p));
        q->rgbGreen = ScaleQuantumToChar(GetPixelGreen(image->image(), p));
        q->rgbBlue = ScaleQuantumToChar(GetPixelBlue(image->image(), p));
        q->rgbReserved = 0;

        p += GetPixelChannels(image->image());
        q++;
    }
}
```

It works when the target bitmap is a 32-bit image. But let's say that the target image is 1-bit. Is there a function in ImageMagick that would allow me to pull data in a way that could be easily translated to 1-bit? I couldn't find another function similar to `ScaleQuantumToChar`. Does ImageMagick support that?

Comment: For the 8 & 24 bit case you need to handle padding each row to a multiple of 4 bytes. You didn't specify what "can't make it work" means, but I assume it just doesn't look right.  Having the 8 & 24 bit part in the question when you really only want a solution to the black and white issue just muddles it IMO.

Comment: For 24-bit put `bitmap.bmWidthBytes = ((bitmap.bmWidth * 24 + 31) / 32) * 4`

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. @RetiredNinja you're right, I'll modify this question in a moment. I've created a new one for this part

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I just tried it, I'm afraid it didn't help. I've created a new question and added code to it, could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Maybe i am misunderstanding, but if you want an "HBITMAP with depth equal to 1" why are you setting bitmap.bmBitsPixel to 32?

Comment: @jwezorek that's just an example how I obtain data when I deal with 32-bit images

Comment: Your question was for 8-bit and 24-bit bitmap, I think you changed it to 1-bit. Note that 8-bit, 4-bit, and 1-bit bitmaps need palette. For 1-bit image, you stick 8 pixels in to one byte, it gets complicated. Your library must have some functions to convert to 1-bit. It should also have some function like `image::getdata()` or `image::getpixel()` to give you all the pixels in one array. Maybe there is a function to get the palette as well.